# What is a word describing words like stuff and thing?

Tags: grammar

A coworker abuses pronouns to the point we don't always understand what he's saying. We asked him to stop using pronouns and he started using words like "the thing", "the stuff". Technically these aren't pronouns.

Is there a technical word explaining what they actually are? The subjective word I keep coming back to is "frustrating."

Comment: If your co-worker used "[the thingamabob](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thingamabob)" or "[the stuffamabob](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stuffamabob)" instead of “the thing” and “the stuff” I’d call them “[placeholders/placeholder names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name), but I’m not sure that it would apply to just “the thing” or “the stuff.”

Comment: I have baptized such nouns "cover-alll nouns". It may be not the best term, but I have a term for such nouns as thing, things, thingummy, matter, stuff, business, gizmo, mess,  the whole shebang etc.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm encompassing the concern about using a definite article *the* for a term, but they could be referred to in general as **vague**, **non-specific**, or **generic** terms.

> [Vague](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vague): Thinking or communicating in an unfocused or imprecise way.
>
> [Non-specific](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonspecific?q=non-specific): Not detailed or exact; general.
>
> [Generic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/generic): Characteristic of or relating to a class or group of things; not specific.